# Скопировать текст из распарсенного json файла

Tags: java, android, json

У меня есть .json файл в котором находится нужная мне строка "name".
Я создал геттер и сеттер:

```
public class Anime {
private String name;
public Anime(String name){this.name = name;}

public String getName() {
    return name;
 }
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }
}
```

Затем я создал адаптер:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private Context mContext ;
private List<Anime> mData;

public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context mContext, List<Anime> mData) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.mData = mData;
}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view ;
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.anime_row_item,parent,false) ;        

    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tv_name.setText(mData.get(position).getName());  
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView tv_name;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        tv_name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.anime_name);
    }
}
```

}

Затем я создал файл MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

private final String JSON_URL = "http://lobanov.space/newnew.json" ;
private JsonArrayRequest request ;
private RequestQueue requestQueue ;
private List<Anime> lstAnime ;
private RecyclerView recyclerView ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);

    lstAnime = new ArrayList<>() ;
    recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewid);
    jsonrequest();

    private void jsonrequest() {

    request = new JsonArrayRequest(JSON_URL, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {

            JSONObject jsonObject  = null ;

            for (int i = 0 ; i < response.length(); i++ ) {
                try {
                    jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i) ;
                    Anime anime = new Anime() ;
                    anime.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                    lstAnime.add(anime);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            setuprecyclerview(lstAnime);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(MainActivity1.this);
    requestQueue.add(request) ;
}

private void setuprecyclerview(List<Anime> lstAnime) {
    RecyclerViewAdapter myadapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this,lstAnime) ;
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myadapter);

}
```

}

У меня так же есть кнопка, которая находится в xml файле, ее имя button_copy. Подскажите, как скопировать в буфер обмена содержимое строки "name", нажав на кнопку button_copy. Может быть это делается с помощью ClipboardManager, на я не смог правильно им воспользоваться в данном коде.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("", "сюда текст который надо добавить в буфер");
                clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            }
        });
```

Comment: В какой из мест кода, нужно вставить это? Потому что я вставляю в адаптер, у меня context подчеркнуто красным цветом.

Comment: @LobanovSpace добавляйте в `onBindViewHolder()`, но сначала кнопку инициализируйте так же как и `TextView tv_name`

Comment: Я добавил ваш код в onCreateViewHolder. Добавив там же:
`Button button_copy = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button_copy);`
`final TextView tv_name =(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.anime_name);`
Код работает, спасибо.
Так же я добавил в метод `onClick` строку `String text = tv_name.getText().toString();`